# how to write contents into a file in python where one part holds a variable and other just a display statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I use a `write()` in Python to write a statement like `"value of a is:",a`?

We use

```
print "value of a is:",a
```

but

```
f.write("value of a is:",a)
```

gives an error. How do I write it into a file??

Comment: What have **you** tried so far?

Comment: Doesn't the question state what he tried?

Comment: @charvi try: `print >>f, "value of a is:", a`

Comment: this s not working ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a is an integer:

```
f.write("value of a is: %d" % (a))
```

If you're looking for a more robust solution, see: [Python string formatting: % vs. .format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is what you are after:

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'w') as the_file:
    the_file.write("value of a is: {}\n".format(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your are look at for these codes:

```
a=10
f=open("test.dat","w")
f.write('valiue is a is:'+str(a))
f.close()
```

Because f.write() expected a character buffer object, you have to convert a in to string to write to your file

Answer (score 0):

[`.write()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) takes a complete string, not one of the following format:

```
"value of a is:",a
```

Instead of calling `f.write("value of a is:",a)`, assign `"value of a is:",a` to a variable first:

```
string = "value of a is:", a
f.write(string)
```